# ¿Alguna alternativa para castear (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()?

Tags: android, google-maps

En condiciones normales funciona de maravilla, no comprendo por que no funciona, les comento que estoy haciendo, abro un DialogFragment que muestra un Mapa; mediante un menupop de un ítem de una galería que esta en un fragment, el detalle consiste que el getFragmentManager() no puede ser casteado por (SupportMapFragment), probando varias opciones en vez de usar SupportMapFragment, trato con MapFragment el cual si permite castear y funciona hasta cierto punto, el app se crashea cuando intento abrir el dialogfragment de otro ítem, me marca un error de duplicidad de xml, abjunto log. tambien abjunto el codigo del xml

alguna alternativa.....

[image: dato]

Código de mi Clase DF_GeolocalizarVisita.java:

```
    public class DF_GeolocalizarVisita extends DialogFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback  {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public LatLng location;
    ImageButton fab_close;
    double Lat;
    double Lon;

    public DF_GeolocalizarVisita(){  }

    static DF_GeolocalizarVisita newInstance() {
        DF_GeolocalizarVisita f = new DF_GeolocalizarVisita();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.df_geolocalizarvisita, container, false);
        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(85,15, 15, 15)));

        fab_close = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab_close);

        Lat = Double.valueOf(getArguments().getString("Lat"));
        Lon = Double.valueOf(getArguments().getString("Lon"));

        //MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_geovisita);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_geovisita);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        fab_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Lat, Lon),15));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_place_white_36dp))
                .anchor(0.5f, 1f)
                .position(new LatLng(Lat, Lon))
                .draggable(false));

    }

}
```

Log del error:

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                  at com.mark.exportadora.Productor.DF_GeolocalizarVisita.onCreateView(DF_GeolocalizarVisita.java:48)
                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2281)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:984)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1164)
                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1557)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:488)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                  at com.mark.exportadora.Productor.DF_GeolocalizarVisita.onCreateView(DF_GeolocalizarVisita.java:48) 
                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2281) 
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:984) 
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1164) 
                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1557) 
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:488) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #28: Duplicate id 0x7f0f016e, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0f016d with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2227)
                  at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:99)
                  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6071)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:36)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                  at com.mark.exportadora.Productor.DF_GeolocalizarVisita.onCreateView(DF_GeolocalizarVisita.java:48) 
                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2281) 
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:984) 
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1164) 
                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1557) 
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:488) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Codigo de df_geolocalizarvisita.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <!--
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_geovisita"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.mark.exportadora.Productor.DF_GeolocalizarVisita" />
    -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_geovisita"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.mark.exportadora.Productor.DF_GeolocalizarVisita" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:keepScreenOn="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_outline_black_48dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema descrito en el mensaje:

> Inconvertible type cannot cast android.app.Fragment to
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

se soluciona tomando la clase Fragment de

```
android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
```

NO de :

```
android.app.DialogFragment;
```

ya que SupportMapFragment extiende de [android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

---

Cambia el `import` que estas empleando a:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

Comment: gracias colega pero era otro import:                                                                           import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

Comment: es verdad veo extiendes de Dialog, pero es lo mismo debe ser la versión de android.support.v4

Comment: pero me marco el erro de xml duplicate